# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'PowerShell'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to reboot a server locally using Tidal Enterprise Scheduler. I have a script but its giving me an error message while running it.

```
$Var = get-content c:\temp\HP_BPM.txt;
$UserName=’na\sa-its-bsm_qa’
$Password= '123456'
$SecurePassword=Convertto-SecureString –String $Password –AsPlainText –force
$MyCred=New-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserName,$SecurePassword
Restart-Computer ($var) -For ’PowerShell’ -Credential $MyCred -Timeout 500 -Delay 5
```

When I am running it, its giving me an error message :-

Restart-Computer : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'PowerShell'

Please assist.

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for suggestion, even after adding -Wait I am getting the almost same error, as I have read and understood the -For parameter, that itself has the wait for specific service feature, so its not mandataroly important to add -Wait.
Restart-Computer : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Wait'.
At line:1 char:30
+ Restart-Computer ($var) -Wait <<<<  -For PowerShell -Credential $MyCred -Timeout 500 -Delay 5
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Restart-Computer],

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Hi Jake, I am using WindowsPowerShell\v1.0.

Comment: `-Wait` `-For` and `-Delay` aren't available until PowerShell 3.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the format of the single quotes you have in your script. They appear to be close quotes instead of straight quotes.  Try pasting into notepad and deleting/retyping all single quotes, then save.

Comment: Changed it, ran it still the same issue..same error message..Even after adding -wait, its giving me the same error message...Not sure what am I missing...

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with missing parameters, all the required parameters are there. This is a basic syntactical error. What exactly is in your c:\temp\HP_BPM.txt file? And, does it need to be a file? If you're targeting a single computer why not put the computer name directly into the Restart cmdlet? If you're targeting multiple computers then you are going to need a foreach loop. Also i don't know that the parentheses are necessary - it might be confusing the ComputerName positional parameter.

Comment: Tried the same :-
Restart-Computer -ComputerName ITSUSMPW00893 -For PowerShell -Credential $MyCred -Timeout 500 -Delay 5

Still the same error....

Comment: Have you tried adding the -Wait parameter as @Jake mentioned? It is required before using the -For parameter, from TechNet: "Waits until the specified service or feature is available after the computer is restarted. Specify one of the valid values. This parameter is valid only with the Wait parameter." [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849837(v=wps.620).aspx). Also, like he said, this parameter wasn't introduced until version 3 but I really doubt you're still on version 1. The installation folder can be misleading - verify by running `$host.version`.